# Text wrapping in SPSS-22 syntax editor

Tags: editor, spss, word-wrap

I use SPSS-22 on a Linux machine.

I would like to know, if I can somehow tell the editor to *automatically introduce line breaks*, once the edge of the window is reached, as I would like to insert some longer comments in the syntax without having to press return all the time.

Comment: I currently use an Emacs Major-Mode for editing SPSS-Files. It would be nice to know, though, as I can't run SPSS directly from Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax editor will turn overly long lines red, but it will not wrap the lines for you.  251 characters is the maximum legal length, but you would probably not want lines that long in your output for readability, so wrapping them yourself is probably warranted.

You might be interested in the TEXT extension command for writing long comments that will appear in separate text blocks in the output rather than being buried in log blocks.  TEXT supports html and rtf markup as well.

TEXT requires the (free) Python Essentials for Statistics.  Details are on the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral), but the Essentials are automatically installed (unless you decline) with Statistics 22.  I think TEXT is included in the Essentials, but if not, you can get it via the Download and Install Extension Bundles feature under Utilities.